# Setting up a redirection

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I am trying to use WordPress's redirect feature to setup a redirect for the following. I can successfully get redirects to work from a page to another page or a page to a PDF in the media. I can't seem to get the following to work.

From: https://www.niimbl.org/Downloads/NIIMBL_2022_2023_Annual_Report.pdf

To: https://www.niimbl.org/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/NIIMBL-2022-2023-Annual-Report-Full.pdf

Below is the configuration I have that I think should work but does not.  I receive a 404 Not Found error.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/422496/edit) to show us what you've tried. This will give us a better understanding of where you might be going wrong and how to help you.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, I don't think that's WordPress native functionality. You should reach out to the support team for the plugin you're using for redirections and see what they have to say.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.